# Node.js: Cannot do PROFIND with request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, webdav, io.js

I'm trying to access content of my WebDAV server in node (server OK, I can net use it). I'm using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module:

```
path = url.join(this._options.rootUrl, path || "");

var data =
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
    "<propfind xmlns=\"DAV:\">" +
    "<propname/>" +
    "</propfind>";

var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "text/xml",
    "Depth": depth || 1
};

var req = request({
    url: path,
    data: data,
    headers: headers,
    method: "PROPFIND",
    json: false,
    encoding: "utf8",
    auth: {
        user: this._options.user,
        password: this._options.password
    }
});

req.on("response", ...);

req.on("error", ...);
```

The problem is I'm getting HTTP 405 instead of the result. I've tried bundled https module, same result.

Is it possible that Node.js cannot invoke costom verbs like PROPFIND?

**UPDATE 1:**

This is stated that node can do PROFIND. So my question is, how do you people do correct WebDAV PROPFIND client request in node/io.js by using request module? (Or anything that works for this purpose.)

Comment: Is it possible that the server doesn't support `<propname />` i know at least some that don't support this. Try removing the entire request body for an easy test. (no requestbody in `PROPFIND` is an `allprop` request).

Comment: Actually the server is OneDrive. There is an already working .NET version of this code that I want to port to io.js. So the request is forged in that way that the server should understand for sure.

Comment: Are you sure that OneDrive supports `<propname />`?

Answer (score 1):

PROPFIND or any other verb is supported just fine for outbound requests in node and iojs. There is either something else wrong with your request (wrong/bad headers or payload for example) or configuration on the server.

Example of PROPFIND working:

```
// client.js
require('http').request({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8000,
  method: 'PROPFIND'
}, function(res) {
  res.resume();
}).end();

// server.js
require('http').createServer(function(req,res) {
  // echoes "PROPFIND" to stdout
  console.log(req.method);

  res.writeHead(200, { 'Connection': 'close' });
  res.end();
}).listen(8000);
```

Comment: Thanks, this anwered the part that node/io.js side can send and recevie costom verbs. But my question is, how do you people do correct WebDAV PROPFIND client request in node/io.js? I have not being able to do it yet. The request should do, see the second comment of my original post.